# React-Native: Error trying to get in touch with native module in the tutorial

Tags: ios, react-native, native-module

Having issue with defining a native module from the tutorial in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html.

```
#import "CalendarManager.h"
#import <React/RCTLog.h>

@implementation CalendarManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(addEvent: (NSString *)name location: (NSString *)location)
{

}
@end
```

It give me the compile error in RCT_EXPORT_METHOD saying

> "Expected ')'"

. 
and

> 'Type specifier missing, defaults to int' (later also appeared under
>   RCT_EXPORT_MODULE)

Answer (score 1):

You need to insert `#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>` in CalendarManager.h either.

Like this

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface CalendarManager : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```